Why is it not possible to define a full path with drive name with pathlib.Path or os.path.join?
For some reason, it is impossible to define a full path using a drive name and colons.
Whenever I include a colon after the drive name, Path will not separate the folders anymore.
The behavior is the same with os.path.join.
I don't understand if this is intended behavior, and if so, what is the sense in that.
How should I specify full paths?
Python 3.12.4 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Jun 18 2024, 15:03:56) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> Path("foo", "bar")
WindowsPath('foo/bar')
>>> Path("C:", "foo", "bar") 
WindowsPath('C:foo/bar')
>>> Path("C", "foo", "bar")  
WindowsPath('C/foo/bar')


"Whenever I include a colon after the drive name, Path will not separate the folders anymore." - this is not apparent from your example. You do realise that C:foo/bar means foo/bar within the current working directory on C:, which is different from C:/foo/bar which means foo/bar in the root of C:?

See this answer or this answer.

My question is how to create the path C:/foo/bar in this manner. This answer seems to imply that os.path.join( "C:", "meshes", "as" ) and r"C:\meshes\as" are equivalent. For me, they are not, because the former command returns 'C:meshes\\as' for me.

@HaukeL., right, because os.path.join doesn't treat C: as identical to C:/ -- which is correct; they have different meanings and it would be wrong to conflate them. The behavior you're seeing is exactly what os.path.join's documentation says it should do. If you want to start from the root instead of the current working directory, start from C:/ not from C:.

(To put it a little differently: os.path.join(*args) is not, and does not want to be, a synonym for os.path.sep.join(args); they're deliberately different functions; the former operates more like "if I start in directory A and then run "cd B", where does that put me?", repeated for each element; so, "if I start in C:, and then cd foo, and then cd bar, where does that put me?" is correctly answered to say that the result is identical to cd "C:foo\bar" with no leading slash anchoring it, because starting in C: starts at the current directory in C:, not the root of C:).

That answer with os.path.join is incorrect as it demonstrates the behavior of posixpath but with the wrong path separator, see comment on that answer. Moreover, it does not describe the behavior with pathlib.WindowsPath which is what your question is specifically about. Finally, if you followed the first answer I linked you should be able to derive what you should have done is WindowsPath("C:", "/", "foo", "bar") or WindowsPath(r"C:/foo/bar").
